# How to find sibling of a student

Tags: mysql, sql, union, siblings

I have a two table in mysql one is student and other is student_sibling with the following structure.

```
Student:

student_id    name  
------------------
1             anu    
2             manu
3             tanu
4             pinu
..            ..
```

student_sibling table:

```
student_id    sibling_student_id
--------------------------------
1              4    
15             4    
2              1    
6              15
```

if i insert sibling of id 1 as 4 the voice-versa is also sibling and in same way 1 is also sibling of 15 and 2
e.g if i want to show sibling of any student_id 4 in mysql then it should shows :

```
1

2

6

15
```

i have tried the following query but it only shows  1 and 15: 
thanks in advance for all great guys

```
SELECT student_id  
FROM `student_sibling` 
WHERE student_id=4 or sibling_student_id=4
UNION 
SELECT sibling_student_id, 
FROM `student_sibling` 
WHERE student_id=4 or sibling_student_id=4
```

Comment: Your table structure isn't very conducive to this type of query. You'll have to map the relationships in `student_sibling` one-to-one. In fact, RDBMS' are not particularly great at following relationships like this, like a graph-style database would be.

Comment: "sibling" is a transitive property (my sibling's sibling should be my sibling -- although that can get complicated with half-siblings).  Do you have all the connections in your table?

Comment: then please suggest better design for table if any.

Comment: Why isn't 4 related to 2 and 15 in your data already in student_Sibling?  and how many levels of nesting can occur?

Comment: yes 4 is related to 2 and 15 also.

Comment: THen why would your attempt only show 1 and 15?  Shouldn't 2 also show if 2 is related to 4?  A MCVE (minimally complete verifiable example) would help

Comment: @xQbert OP in his question say: "should show : 1,2,6,15" and then he tell's us that he has try something that returns him only 1 and 15. So, he is not attempting to show only 1 and 15. He is attempting to show 1,2,6 and 15.

Comment: @HaryanviDevloper, What is your MySQL Version?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL version 8.0 or higher and you may use below recursive query -

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE AS (SELECT student_id
                       FROM student_sibling
                       WHERE sibling_student_id=4
                       UNION
                       SELECT S.student_id
                       FROM CTE C
                       JOIN student_sibling S ON S.sibling_student_id = C.student_id)
SELECT student_id FROM CTE
ORDER BY student_id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fd79dc6dc02d4981d0fe30eb525cc648) is the fiddle.

Comment: I think this is not correct. Here is the demo with some more data: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f7f10075112f14cfc601c894277c682f

Comment: Maybe this is correct for what the OP is looking for. But I am not sure if the number 33 (from my example) needs to be in the answer(and the OP needs to confirm that...). From what I have understood it does. Here is the demo(with my example data and your code): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8f4724ed79ef3fb81a578f10027f66a6